# How to simplify an if condition having multiple OR cases

Tags: c#

I have a condition in C# like below:

```
if( myString.Contains("UCK") OR
    myString.Contains("SAN") OR
    myString.Contains("AVB") OR
    myString.Contains("AVM") OR
    myString.Contains("SDS") OR
    myString.Contains("DWW") OR
    myString.Contains("WQP") OR
    myString.Contains("LHG") OR
  )
{
 mySecondString = "CATEGORY A";
}

else if( myString.Contains("UCT") OR
    myString.Contains("SAM") OR
    myString.Contains("AHJB") OR
    myString.Contains("AVR") OR
  )
{
 mySecondString = "CATEGORY B";
}

else if( myString.Contains("UKC") OR
    myString.Contains("SHZ") OR
    myString.Contains("EEB") OR
  )
{
 mySecondString = "CATEGORY C";
}

else  mySecondString = "CATEGORY D";
```

I want to make it more professional. What is the best way you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: There's no `OR` in C#, do you mean `||` ?

Comment: Is this list likely to change? If so, I'd create a table in your database assuming your application uses one. Otherwise, I'd create a `Dictionary<string, string>` where `Key` is each string like "UCK", "SAN", etc. and `Value` is each category. This is more of an *opinion* than an *answer* of course, which is why it's here in the comments rather than posted as an authoritative answer.

Comment: What does the input string look like?  Is it in a consistent form, such as a list of comma separated values?  Or is it just random text?  Can you provide an example?  Also, is it case sensitive?  (These look like airport codes, so I'd guess not)

Comment: creating a list<string> would probably be the best bet if you don't want to reference a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string self, params string[] criteria)
{
    foreach (string s in criteria)
    {
        if (self.Contains(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

call it like this:

```
if (myString.ContainsAny("UCK", "SAN", "AVB", "AVM", "SDS", "DWW", "WQP", "LHG"))
{
    mySecondString = "CATEGORY A";
}

else if (myString.ContainsAny("UCT", "SAM", "AHJB", "AVR"))
{
    mySecondString = "CATEGORY B";
}

else if (myString.ContainsAny("UKC", "SHZ", "EEB"))
{
    mySecondString = "CATEGORY C";
}

else
{
    mySecondString = "CATEGORY D";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Could use a [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx) I'm not the best regex maker:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(myString, "/(LHG)|(UCK)|(SAN)|(AVB)|(AVM)|(SDS)|(DWW)|(WQP)/")) {
    mySecondString = "CATEGORY A";
} else ...
```

[Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester) is a good place to test regexes for C#

Answer (score 4):

Although I like Mr Anderson's solution of having an extension method, if you just wanted it done quick and dirty:

```
        if (new[] { "UCK", "SAN", "AVB", "AVM", "SDS", "DWW", "WQP", "LHG" }.Any(s => myString.Contains(s)))
        {
            mySecondString = "CATEGORY A";
        }

        else if (new[] { "UCT", "SAM", "AHJB", "AVR" }.Any(s => myString.Contains(s)))
        {
            mySecondString = "CATEGORY B";
        }

        else if (new[] { "UKC", "SHZ", "EEB" }.Any(s => myString.Contains(s)))
        {
            mySecondString = "CATEGORY C";
        }

        else
        {
            mySecondString = "CATEGORY D";
        }
```

Comment: Mh, that's not equivalent. Didn't downvote though :P

Comment: This will only match if the array contains the exact value based on `Object.Equals()` - different from `String.Contains()`

Comment: And that's why you read the question properly:P. How about the edited answer?

Comment: I like it. I forgot to use `Any()` in my answer. Oh well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Best approach in my opinion is to use a `Map` (in Java) or `Dictionary` in C#:

```
class MyExample {
    // declaring your static map (should be private static final)
    private static Dictionary<String, String> myPreciousMap = new HashMap<>();

    public MyExample() {
        String categoryA = "CATEGORY A";
        String categoryX = "CATEGORY X"; // you know, A, B, C, D etc
        myPreciousMap.Add("UCK", categoryA);
        myPreciousMap.Add("SAN", categoryA);
        myPreciousMap.Add("X", categoryX);
    }

    // using it
    public String getCategory(String myString) {
        // this returns exact match (which is recommended)
        // return myPreciousMap.GetValue(myString);

        // this is using the contains
        foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myPreciousMap) {
            if (myString.contains(kvp.getKey()) return kvp.getValue();
        }
        return "Some sort of Default";
    }
}
```

This way, you avoid all ifs and makes very easy to see correspondent values and edit them.

Comment: This is not equivalent. `myString` could be "xyzUCK123" and you want it to map to "CATEGORY A" because it *contains* "UCK".

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It is true the map does not go for "contains" match, but a minor change would do the job. The point here is to remove that bunch of ugly and hard-to-understand "ifs". So if you have to run iterate over the map using contains (which is simple) so be it. Again IMHO, it is far better than using any other chain of "if" clauses

Comment: Just edited the code to fit the example. Once again, the question was "How to simplify an if condition having multiple OR cases"

Comment: Indeed with this change the code does the job, and it is more versatile as it is table-driven: you can easily just add another category, for example. My only remaining reservation is that you are now using a Dictionary as just a collection of pairs. The Dictionary internally maintains a hash table which is not being used at all. However, if you want a collection of pairs, a Dictionary is simple to use even if not the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the suggestion to use an extension, but applies whether you do or not:

If you have a condition this long, you should isolate it in its own function, for example:

```
string GetCategory(string input)
{
    //all of your conditions
    return mySecondString;
}
```

Then in the method that used to contain this condition you just have the function call instead, like

```
var category = GetCategory(myString);
```

This does a few things:

- It makes the method that calls it more readable. Calling the function in a sense acts like a comment. Instead of having all of those conditions and wondering what it's for, they'll see the call to `GetCategory` and understand that you're getting the category. Similarly, when they look at the `GetCategory` function itself they'll understand what that code is for from the name of the function that it's in.
- It keeps the calling function shorter. 15 lines or less is a good recommendation. This condition itself is about that size, so separating it ensures that the calling function won't get too long.

Another suggestion - use constants, like

```
const string AliensVersusBovines = "AVB";
```

That prevents someone from reading this:

```
myString.Contains("AVB")
```

and wondering what "AVB" is, since it's not self-explanatory. If you're going to use that string in multiple classes (which seems likely) then you could create a separate class that just contains all of those constants. That keeps you from having the same string literal scattered throughout your code which can become a maintenance issue.

```
public class Codes
{
    public const string AliensVersusBovines = "AVB";
}
```

That way your code can read

```
myString.Contains(Codes.AliensVersusBovines)
```