# Best way to simplify if with multiple OR cases using db

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm working on a project where various files are to be uploaded to a platform. The platform has over 100 `DocumentTypeId`s. The files have no set naming convention. So in order to determine a file's `DoumentTypeId` I'm currently doing this in a method that returns a string

```cs
if (fileName.Contains("401k") || fileName.Contains("401(k)") || fileName.Contains("457b") || fileName.Contains("457(b)") || fileName.Contains("retire"))
{
    return "401k-and-retirement";
}
else if (fileName.Contains("aflac"))
{
    return "aflac";
}
else if ( fileName.Contains("beneficiary form") || fileName.Contains("beneficiaries") || fileName.Contains("beneficiary")
)
{
    return "beneficiary-forms";
}
else if (fileName.Contains("benefit enrollment") || fileName.Contains("benefits enrollment") || fileName.Contains("benefit form") || fileName.Contains("benefits form") || fileName.Contains("benefit paperwork") || fileName.Contains("qualifying event") || fileName.Contains("enrollment") || fileName.Contains("b enroll") || fileName.Contains("benefit enrollnent")) //yes, the typo is on purpose. there are typos in some of the file names to import
{
    return "benefits-election";
}
//etc
```

As you can imagine, this method is disgustingly ugly and long (~300 lines). I want to refactor this and make use of a database. I'm thinking of having a table with two fields `DocumentTypeId` and `FileNameContains` where `FileNameContains` is a comma-separated list of the `OR` case strings. This would allow for adding any cases without doing any code changes.

What I'm unsure about is how to do a `string.Contains()` comparison on a database. I'm aware of `LIKE` but that's not quite the same as `string.Contains()`. I've also thought about querying the database to convert `FileNameContains` field into an array or List for each record and doing an extension method([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339535/how-to-simplify-an-if-condition-having-multiple-or-cases))  that loops through and does a `string.Contains()`. But that doesn't seem very efficient and fast.

Am I approaching this wrong? I just know there has to be a better way than a bunch of `else if` statements with `OR` cases. And I really think having a database would make this more elegant and scalable without any code changes and purely SQL `UPDATE` statements. Some help and input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing, don't use a comma separated column for the filenames, add a row per documentid/filetype combination. Then its just a case of finding a match in your list which is trivial.

Comment: If your software does not already have a database, I personally wouldn’t use a database to store this mapping. You could use a JSON config file, or even some type of delimited file and load it into a Dictionary.

Comment: As far as your question here, SQL uses `LIKE`, with support for wildcards in the clause. You should find a good SQL tutorial, as this is basic information about the use of SQL that should be covered in any tutorial or book. But, as @DaleK says, using a comma-separated value column is a sign of poor table design - that tutorial should also help you with properly creating columns in your table, as well as basic database design.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a dictionary, or list of keyvaluepair.. the key being "find this", the value being "the file type"

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>{
  { "401k", "401k-and-retirement" }, 
  { "401(k)", "401k-and-retirement" },
  { "457b", "401k-and-retirement" },
  { "457(b)", "401k-and-retirement" },
  { "retire", "401k-and-retirement" },
  { "aflacs", "aflacs" },
  ...
};

foreach(var kvp in d)
   if(filename.Contains(kvp.Key)) return kvp.Value;
```

Add more entries to your list/dict, or even fill it from a db

> What I'm unsure about is how to do a string.Contains() comparison on a database

Well, you could transport this same concept into the db and store your values like this in your table:

```
Find, Ret
%401k%, 401k-and-retirement
%401(k)%, 401k-and-retirement
```

And query like:

```
SELECT ret FROM table WHERE @pFilename LIKE Find
```

With a c# side parameter of

```
//adjust type and size to match your column
command.Parameters.Add("@pFilename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "my401k.txt";
```

Or whatever equivalent you'll use in Dapper, EF etc..

```
context.FindRets.FirstOrDefault(fr => EF.Functions.Like(filename, fr.Find))
```

---

For the love of a relevant deity, please don't store a CSV in a table column. It will bite you sooner than later

Comment: Note that there is a slight semantic difference in that a dictionary and a table have no ordering, so if there are multiple matches you get an arbitrary result. I've implemented something similar to this recently and used an `Ordering` column, taking the first match

Answer (score 0):

I would usually do something like this:

```
var contains = new []
{
    new
    {
        find = new [] { "401k", "401(k)", "457b", "457(b)", "retire" },
        result = "401k-and-retirement"
    },
    new { find = new [] { "aflac" }, result = "aflac" },
    new
    {
        find = new [] { "beneficiary form", "beneficiaries", "beneficiary" },
        result = "beneficiary-forms"
    },
    new
    {
        find = new []
        {
            "benefit enrollment", "benefits enrollment", "benefit form", "benefits form", "benefit paperwork",
            "qualifying event", "enrollment", "b enroll", "benefit enrollnent"
        },
        result = "benefits-election"
    },
};

return
    contains
        .Where(x => x.find.Any(f => fileName.Contains(f)))
        .Select(x => x.result)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

The advantage is that it's easier to add and maintain the items you're looking for. It's all on one portion of the screen.

You could go one step further and save this away in a text file that looks like this:

```
401k-and-retirement
 401k
 401(k)
 457b
 457(b)
 retire
aflac
 aflac
beneficiary-forms
 beneficiary form
 beneficiaries
 beneficiary
benefits-election
 benefit enrollment
 benefits enrollment
 benefit form
 benefits form
 benefit paperwork
 qualifying event
 enrollment
 b enroll
 benefit enrollnent
```

Then you can do this:

```
var contains =
    File
        .ReadLines("config.txt")
        .Aggregate(
            new[] { new { find = new List<string>(), result = "" } }.ToList(),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                if (x.StartsWith(' '))
                {
                    a.Last().find.Add(x.Substring(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    a.Add(new { find = new List<string>(), result = x });
                }
                return a;
            }, a => a.Skip(1).ToArray());
            
contains.Dump();

return
    contains
        .Where(x => x.find.Any(f => fileName.Contains(f)))
        .Select(x => x.result)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you can just add more items to the config file as you need.